# KOMA letter: how to put images side-by-side, like subfigure?

Tags: graphics, koma-script, subfloats, letters

Using KOMA letter, I'd like to have a 2 x 2 image section, with a caption below each image. KOMA letter does not allow me to do something like

```
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
    \end{subfigure}        
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image2}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

What's the best way to get such an image section in a KOMA letter?

Comment: Replace `figure*` with `center` (or `\twocolumn[...]` if using columns) and `subfigure` with `minipage`.

Comment: You could use class `scrartcl` and load package `scrletter` if you really need floats with captions in the letter.